# How to get all master table rows in nested html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table like below
[image]

I want to get all rows from master table but I got all rows both master and child/nested table. My code is given below----

```
 var $rows = $('#tableID tr:has(td)');
```

Please help me in this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/k4zsLuke/1/):

```
var tr = $('#tableID tr').not('table table tr').not('tr:has(table)');
```

Comment: I have solved by the following code $('#tableID tr:has(td)').not('table table tr')

Comment: Glad it has been solved but it was not clear without your `HTML` code :-)

Comment: <table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td> </td>
     <td> </td>
      <td>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
         <td> </td>
    <tr>
 </table
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> </td>
     <td> </td>
      <td>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
         <td> </td>
    <tr>
 </table
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td> </td>
     <td> </td>
      <td>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
         <td> </td>
    <tr>
 </table
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Should be `$('#tableID>tr:has(td)');` This will select the direct descendants, whereas you were selecting all descendants.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have applied and failed to get all rows.

Comment: The table's html I mean